# PHP array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the below array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 08:30
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 09:00
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 09:30
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-14
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 08:30
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-15
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 09:00
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-15
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 09:30
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-15
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 08:30
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-16
        )

)
```

I like the array should be

```
Array(
 [2011-07-14] => Array
    (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reservation_time] => 08:30
                    [user_name] => 
                    [reason] => 
                    [comments] => recursive
                    [reservation_date] => 2011-07-14
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reservation_time] => 09:00
                    [user_name] => 
                    [reason] => 
                    [comments] => recursive
                    [reservation_date] => 2011-07-14
                )
    )
 [2011-07-15]  => Array
 ( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reservation_time] => 08:30
            [user_name] => 
            [reason] => 
            [comments] => recursive
            [reservation_date] => 2011-07-15
        )
)
```

How can i loop this array to get the desired output

Regards 
Nisanth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
  $new_array[$item['reservation_date']][] = $item;
}
```

Comment: I was about to answer pretty the same, +1 to you

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's nice to get a multidimensional array grouped by subkey - any subkey. This is basically like the accepted answer but overloading the actual array:

```
print_r($array('reservation_date')); # group by subkey 'reservation_date'
```

Code ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Jxeoxl.php53_t)):

```
$array = array(
  0 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '08:30',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-14',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '09:00',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-14',
  ),
  2 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '09:30',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-14',
  ),
  3 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '08:30',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-15',
  ),
  4 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '09:00',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-15',
  ),
  5 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '09:30',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-15',
  ),
  6 => array(
    'reservation_time' => '08:30',
    'user_name' => '',
    'reason' => '',
    'comments' => 'recursive',
    'reservation_date' => '2011-07-16',
  ),
);

// overload $array with a function
$array = function($key) use ($array) {
    $r = array();
    foreach($array as $v) 
        $r[$v[$key]][] = $v;
    return $r;
};

// request subkey per parameter:

print_r($array('reservation_date'));

print_r($array('reservation_time'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From my own PHP code, I have function for this. Just call
`make_assoc_from_list($your_array, 'reservation_date')`:

```
// makes associative array from normal list
//      - $list - list
//      - $key - key of each item which will be the associative key
//

function make_assoc_from_list($list, $key)
{
        $assoc = array();
        if ($list === null)
                $list = array();
        foreach ($list as $item)
                $assoc[$item[$key]] = $item;
        return $assoc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    if (!array_key_exists($entry['reservation_date'], $new)) $new[$entry['reservation_date']] = array();
    $new[$entry['reservation_date']][] = $entry;
}
```

Comment: yes, pressed TAB and SPACE...and answer was commited :( so please remove downvote